# How to implement a function for different vector of structs with traits?

Tags: rust

I have 3 `Vec<T>` structs that shared the same function:

```
Vec<RawTransaction>
Vec<RawCashTransaction>
Vec<RawAdjustmentTransaction>
```

All three shared the same `VerifyableRaw` traits and the `verify()` function. I use the `verify()` function check the validity of the content of that array/vector.

Here's my implementation. As you can see, all of them shared the same basic fields, namely: `date`, `total`, `credit`, and `debit`.

My problem is: since I use the same fields that those structs shared, the `verify()` function is the same for all of them. In `verify` function, I need to access the `date`, `total`, `credit`, and `debit` fields so I just copy and paste the code from one implementation to another.

My question is: Can I refactor this trait implementation into a single function definition ?

I found out that I need to repeat myself each time I need to use `verify()` function and `VerifyableRaw` trait to another struct that needs it

```
pub struct RawTransaction {
    pub date: Option<NaiveDate>,
    pub contact_name: String,
    pub total: Option<Decimal>,
    pub credit: String,
    pub debit: String,
}

pub struct RawCashTransaction{
    pub tr_type: String,
    pub date: Option<NaiveDate>,
    pub contact_name: String,
    pub total: Option<Decimal>,
    pub credit: String,
    pub debit: String,
}

pub struct RawAdjustmentTransaction{
    pub date: Option<NaiveDate>,
    pub info: String,
    pub total: Option<Decimal>,
    pub credit: String,
    pub debit: String,
}
```

Here's my trait implementation:

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait VerifyableRaw {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl VerifyableRaw for Vec<RawTransaction> {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err> {
        /// .... this function is the same for all three

        let data = &self; // access the vector
        for (i, row) in data.iter().enumerate() {
            // enumerate each item in this vector
            let date = row.date.unwrap(); // check if the date is valid, etc
            let de = row.debit.clone(); // check if this value is valid
            let cr = row.credit.clone(); // check if this value is valid
            //  ... another process here ...
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl VerifyableRaw for Vec<RawCashTransaction> {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err> {
        /// .... this function is exactly the same as RawTransaction above
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl VerifyableRaw for Vec<RawAdjustmentTransaction> {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err> {
        /// .... this function is exactly the same as RawTransaction above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid repetition, you can put the common fields in a struct, and instead of copying every field into each concrete struct, simply include a single field whose type is the common one:

```
pub struct BaseTransaction {
    pub date: Option<NaiveDate>,
    pub total: Option<Decimal>,
    pub credit: String,
    pub debit: String,
}

pub struct RawTransaction {
    pub base: BaseTransaction,
    pub contact_name: String,
}

pub struct RawCashTransaction{
    pub base: BaseTransaction,
    pub tr_type: String,
    pub contact_name: String,
}

pub struct RawAdjustmentTransaction{
    pub base: BaseTransaction,
    pub info: String,
}
```

Then `impl AsRef<BaseTransaction>` for each concrete type:

```
impl AsRef<BaseTransaction> for RawTransaction {
    fn as_ref (&self) -> &BaseTransaction {
        &self.base
    }
}
impl AsRef<BaseTransaction> for RawCashTransaction {
    fn as_ref (&self) -> &BaseTransaction {
        &self.base
    }
}
impl AsRef<BaseTransaction> for RawAdjustmentTransaction {
    fn as_ref (&self) -> &BaseTransaction {
        &self.base
    }
}
```

and now you can have a single generic function that operates on `AsRef<BaseTransaction>`:

```
impl<T: AsRef<BaseTransaction>> VerifyableRaw for Vec<T> {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err> {
        let base: BaseTransaction = self.as_ref();
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```rust
pub trait VerifyableRaw {
    fn date(&self) -> Option<NativeDate>;
    fn credit(&self) -> &str;
    fn debit(&self) -> &str;
}

pub trait VerifyableRaws {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err>;
}

impl VerifyableRaw for RawCashTransaction {
  fn date(&self) -> Option<NativeDate> { self.date }
  fn credit(&self) -> &str { &self.credit }
  fn debit(&self) -> &str { &self.debit }
}

impl<T: VerifyableRaw> VerifyableRaws for Vec<T> {
    async fn verify(&self, cid: String, db: Database) -> Result<bool, Err> {
        // your implementation here, but replace field access with method calls
    }
}

// other types have the same implementation
```

You still have to write implementation for the access method for every type, but I believe it's better than duplicate complex business logic.

If you have too many types like that and you don't want to write getters manually for each of them it's quite trivial to write a macro that will do it for you. But for just 3 types I would not recommend it for macros make things much more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: The concept of this answer is right, but the example code is not. Note that the OP tries to impl `VerifyableRaw` for a `Vec` of the other structs, not for the other structs directly. That is, they would need a helper trait (e.g. `VerifyableRawItem`) for each struct that has the getters and have the `VerifyableRaw` (having only the `verify` method) impl'd for `Vec<T> where T: VerifyableRawItem`, or, if the OP ever wants to mix the different structs in the same `Vec`, `Vec<Box<dyn VerifyableRawItem>>`.

Comment: @FZs You are right. I corrected the code.