# How to port C++ inheritance to Rust?

Tags: inheritance, rust

I'm trying to implement the Rust equivalent code of the following C++ code which makes use of inheritance, but got stuck. This is my sample code:

```cpp
class Vehicle {
public:
    double lat;
    double lon;
    double alt;

    double speed;
};
    
class CabVehicle : public Vehicle {
    
};
    
class PackerMoverVehicle : public Vehicle {
    
};
    
int main() {
    CabVehicle cv;
    cv.lat = 12.34;
    cv.lon = 12.34;
    cv.alt = 12.34;

    PackerMoverVehicle pmv;
    pmv.lat = 12.34;
    pmv.lon = 12.34;
    pmv.alt = 12.34;
}
```

How should this be written in Rust?

Comment: There's no inheritance in rust. Not like this, anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163713/5397009 ?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How do I achieve the same functionality in rust. I know I can keep two separate structs namely `CabVehicle` and `PackerMoverVehicle` but I have to repeat lot of fields which I feel isn't good

Comment: Jmb's answer or this [Is it possible for one struct to extend an existing struct, keeping all the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552698/442760) should have what you want.

Comment: @Jmb of course i can create a separate struct which includes common fields and then make a member variable of it in `CabVehicle` struct. But to access fields I have to use an intermediate member variable, which I feel awkward.

Comment: Rust is not an object-oriented language, so there is no data inheritance mechanism and you have to use composition if you want to avoid repeating fields.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74637514/5397009

Comment: It feels awkward becase you are thinking in C++ while writing Rust. If you could explain some particular problem that your C++ design solves, then maybe we could suggest how to solve that in idiomatic Rust. But as-is, your C++ hiearchy does nothing.

Comment: @rodrigo but don't you think it's a good feature.

Comment: @rodrigo Also if vehicle location needs to be displayed, a member function can be defined only in base class and use it for any of the derived class objects. But in rust I have to implement say "DisplayLocation" trait separately for each vehicle type, since it needs access to fields

Comment: You can implement the trait for your `struct Shared` and implement `AsRef<Shared>` for all that share it to avoid implementing the trait in question multiple times.

Comment: I came to Rust from C++, too. I've been there, trying to do inheritance with Rust... and it _can_ be done, sometimes it even feels right. There are plenty of discussions out there about the goods and evils of inheritance in modern programming, such as this [nice one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260354).

Comment: Usually aggregation is almost as good as inheritance in reusing code, while being way more flexible. See this simple [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c51a63934ab88847f748ac39043ef432).

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is to use composition instead of inheritance. Depending on the application, there can be different ways the composition should go. In most cases, you should start with

```rust
struct VehicleState {
    lat: f64,
    lon: f64,
    alt: f64,
    speed: f64,
}
```

The remaining question then is how your different types of vehicles are going to be used.

---

Way 1: If different parts of the code use the different types of vehicles in distinct, non-overlapping ways, you might simply contain the state struct in the specific structs:

```rust
struct Cab {
    state: VehicleState,
    // ... other fields
}

struct PackerMover {
    state: VehicleState,
    // ... other fields
}
```

This is the version most directly analogous to C++ inheritance, particularly in memory layout and in static typing. However, this makes it awkward to access the common `state` for different vehicles, and it does not support dynamic dispatch, unless you write a trait with a method to access `state` (which comes with some limitations in the kinds of code you can write). You should generally avoid this approach unless you know you don't need anything else.

---

Way 2: If there is code which should be generic over which kind of vehicle is in use, but this is statically decided, you might make a generic struct:

```rust
struct Vehicle<T> {
    state: VehicleState,
    details: T,
}

struct Cab { /* ... */ }
struct PackerMover { /* ... */ }

/// This function only works with Cabs
fn foo(vehicle: Vehicle<Cab>) { /* ... */ } 
    
/// This function works with any Vehicle
fn foo<T>(vehicle: Vehicle<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

This makes it easy to access the `state`, and all usage is statically dispatched.

It can be dynamically dispatched too if you make one small change to `Vehicle` and add a trait:

```rust
struct Vehicle<T: ?Sized> { /* ... */
//              ^^^^^^^^ remove default restriction on the type parameter

trait VehicleDetails { /* add methods here */ }
impl VehicleDetails for Cab { /* ... */ }
impl VehicleDetails for PackerMover { /* ... */ }
```

This allows you to coerce a reference (or pointer or `Box` too) `&Vehicle<Cab>` into `&Vehicle<dyn VehicleDetails>`, which is a type that a pointer to *any* `Vehicle` whose `T` implements `VehicleDetails`. This can be used to put a variety of vehicles in a `Vec<Box<Vehicle<dyn VehicleDetails>>>`, for example. Using `dyn` causes dispatch through vtables, like C++ virtual methods.

([Info on this language feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html). The documentation says that “custom DSTs are a largely half-baked feature for now” but this particular case is exactly the case where they *do* work without any trouble.)

This is not a good choice if you want to be able to find out which “subclass” is being used and interact with it specifically; it is a good choice if all particular characteristics of the vehicle can be expressed within the `VehicleDetails` trait.

---

Way 3: If the application is going to be *routinely* working with dynamically-chosen vehicle types — especially if it frequently wants to ask the question “is this vehicle a `Cab`” and then interact with its `Cab`ness — then you should probably use an `enum` to contain the details.

```rust
struct Vehicle {
   state: VehicleState,
   kind: VehicleKind,
}

enum VehicleKind {
    Cab {
        seats: u16,
    },
    PackerMover {
        cargo_capacity: u64,
    }
}
```

This is dynamically dispatched in the sense that every `Vehicle` can be any kind, so you can always mix-and-match vehicle kinds, but without involving any pointers or vtables. The main disadvantage is that extending it to new kinds requires modifying the single `enum VehicleKind`, so this is not suitable for a library whose users would be writing subclasses in C++. However, this is a lot less fiddly to work with than the `Vehicle<dyn VehicleDetails>` I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Rust is basically more like a procedural and a functional language with some pseudo-OO features, it’s simultaneously lower-level and more abstract than C++ (closer to C or even to C—, but with ZCA and stronger typing). The answer is: there’s no inheritance in Rust, use composition or just rewrite the whole structure. This may look wild for you, but after some time you will understand that there’s no need in inheritance.